# How do I resize my JMenuItem to fit a JButton?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jmenu

Here is the code I am using:

```
JMenu menu = new JMenu("Menu");

JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem("Add");
item.add(new JButton("SOMETHING A BIT WORDY"));
menu.add(item);

// ... 
JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
menuBar.addMenu(menu);
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

// ...
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible();
```

However, the button (inside of the menu item) appears small and only contains the text "..." which is used when the button's size cannot fit the intended text. Is there any way to make my JMenuItem "grow" to fit my JButton (or JTextArea, or JLabel, or whatever the Component may be)?

Comment: Why would you want to put a button in a menu?

Comment: I'd actually like to put a JTextField and a JButton, to allow a user to have a context menu which takes input.

Comment: I recommend a menuitem which invokes a small dialog box to contain the textfield and the button.

Comment: Pop a dialog with those, instead.  A button in a menu is an odd mix, but a text area in a menu would be unworkable.

Comment: I cannot stand dialog boxes and would prefer to stay away from them. I appreciate the suggestions though.

Comment: A menu item isn't intended to be used as a container. Even if you got this working on one platform, it might fail on another, e.g. due to event routing differences.

Comment: I understand that this may not be possible / feasible, but JMenuItems are AWT containers in that they extend the Container class.

Comment: Do you really want a menu, or could you do with a JPopup instead? That is, do you need other menu items beside the textfield/button?

Comment: No, I suppose I don't - that seems to be the best solution for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I totally agree with others who posted their comments, it may be an odd mix to put an button in the menuitem, if you insist to this, setPreferredSize can solve your problem.
I used a bad hard code implementation, if anyone know how to set the width dynamically, please guide me too. :P thx in advance.

```
JMenu menu = new JMenu("Menu");

JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem("Add");
item.add(new JButton("SOMETHING A BIT WORDY"));
item.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); // set FlowLayout for item
item.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100)); // hard code implementation :-(
menu.add(item);

// ... 
JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
menuBar.add(menu);
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

// ...
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

[image]

Comment: To calculate JButton size dynamically use [`FontMetrics#stringWidth(..)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html#stringWidth(java.lang.String))

Comment: Thank you - it's nice to know that is is possible.